# for what reason is the string constantly inserted at the end of the file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I want to insert a line with a user test999 before a construction site with a user test3 .I can't insert a line before another one, it is constantly inserted into the last one, for what reason can this happen?

```
---
- hosts: app_stage
  become: yes
  vars:
    user: test999
  tasks:
    - name: remove immutable
      file:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        attr: '-i'
    - name: change permission
      file:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        mode: 0660
    - name: Allow ‘user’ to have passwordless sudo
      lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/sudoers
        state: present
        regexp: '^test3 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
        insertbefore: '^test3 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
        line: '{{ user }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
        validate: visudo -cf %s
    - name: change permissions back
      file:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        mode: 0440
        owner: root
        group: root
    - name: back immutable
      file:
        path: /etc/sudoers
        attr: '+i'
```

Comment: To make things easier and if possible in your environment and infrastructure, you may have a look into the [`template`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35468363/6771046) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) module documentation for `insertbefore`:

*Used with `state=present`*

*If specified regular expression has no matches, the line will be inserted at the end of the file.*

*If regular expressions are passed to both `regexp` and `insertbefore`, `insertbefore` is only honored if no match for regexp is found.*

Comment: of course i use state: present (sorry for my mistake), but i used only insertbefore and only regexp, but still the line was put down. is it possible to somehow debug this? as I understand it, the fact is that he does not find matches, but they are there

Comment: Try to come up with a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question. We cannot help without complete information

Comment: @Iceforest, if I would have to bet on where your problem is, probably the regexp is not matching because you have more than one space or tabs in your sudoers file